# 180 degree plug adapter

Tags: electrical, cord-and-plug

I am trying to charge my car at my workplace however the 110V plugs in the garage are "upside down" and my charging cable is designed to hang downward when the 110V plug is "right side up".

Is there a 180 degree plug adapter? I've looked around for it (I'm sure it exists) but can't find one beyond a very short extension cable.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just flip the outlets around?

Comment: @whatsisname  Just **try** messing with your company's wiring :-(

Comment: @CarlWitthoft: it can be pretty easy, I've done it. I spoke to the office manager, said I needed a few outlets in certain places, he said "no problem" and in a week or so they were there. It can go just as easily for the OP.

Answer (score 5):

Since some corporations are really grouchy about changing anything, and you may well run into this same problem when trying to charge up at some random location, I would go with either a 3-foot extension cord or a power strip.  In either case, make sure the wire gauge is sufficient for the expected charging current.
Keep this "adapter" in your car next to the charging cable and you'll be compatible with any outlet anywhere.